# Numpy, creating 1D array in C++ segfaults

Tags: python, c++, numpy, boost-python

I am trying to create a 1D array for numpy in c++:

```
PyObject* foo()
{
   npy_intp length[1];
   length[0] = 10;
   PyObject* my_array = PyArray_SimpleNew(1, length, NPY_DOUBLE);
   return boost::python::incref(my_array);
}
```

Then I make a python module:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(pyMod)
{
    using namespace boost::python;

    import_array();

    def("foo", foo);
}
```

When I run this in python, calling foo(), it segfaults when executing the call to PyArray_SimpleNew, even though I have called import_array, which seems to be the common cause to this segfaulting. If I make a 2D array of dimensions [10, 1], it works well, i.e:

```
PyObject* foo()
{
   npy_intp length[2] = {10, 1};
   PyObject* my_array = PyArray_SimpleNew(2, length, NPY_DOUBLE);
   return boost::python::incref(my_array);
}
```

In python it is used like this

```
import numpy as np
import pyMod

if __name__ == "__main__":
    v = pyMod.foo()
```

Any ideas of why this segfaults?

Comment: On what line does it segfault? Please provide a [mcve] with detailed error message (*not* just a function; show us how you call it too)

Comment: It segfaults when calling PyArray_SimpleNew

Comment: My comment was more than just the very first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you exposed the PyObject* to Python, but I think the right way is to expose it by means of boost::python::object.

Another point is that you are calling boost::python::object using a PyObject. Altough it's possible, it's not recommended (see the [guidelines](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/cplusplus-sig/2008-October/013895.html) written by David Abrahams). So boost::python::handle should be used to address this situation.

```
boost::python::object foo()
{
   npy_intp dims[1] = {10};
   PyObject* p_array = PyArray_SimpleNew(boost::size(dims), dims, NPY_FLOAT);
   boost::python::handle<> handle(boost::python::borrowed(p_array));
   return boost::python::object(handle);
}
```

Comment: Dont think this is the issue, as it crashes before return and works with 2D arrays. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: Just because it's working with 2D arrays doesn't means it's right. I've edited the answer providing a link that explains the importance of handle.

Comment: But then I would need a converter from boost::python::object which just returns incref(boost_py_obj->ptr()): PyObject* convert(boost::python::object obj) { return boost::python::incref(obj->ptr)); }?

Comment: I have edited the question to not use boost::python::object, then I dont need the handle, since I am not going through boost::python::object?